# Ltd. in a logo design

Tags: logo

I am making a logo for a company that is an Ltd.  - does the Ltd. need to appear in the Logo itself? The logo is a combination of text with a graphic worked in beneath it.

Answer (score 7):

It would be the designer's choice how much to emphasize "limited" or "Ltd.", unless the client has specified something. Technically, the "limited" *is* part of the company name.

Some companies include it, others don't.

For example:

[image: lucasfilm]

You can also choose to spell out "Limited" rather than using the abbreviation.

There are examples of others that go a different route. For example Adobe Systems Incorporated, does not use the full company name for any logo:

[image]